# setup database environment with xorm module

Tags: go

I tried to execute the go.mod to insert the records by scripts to MySQL. But it gives me error .

I am trying to setup the server like this project in Windows.
https://github.com/Kirk-Wang/nanoserver

I can create database by executing

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.mysql.yaml up
```

. But when I execute

```
go run .
```

,  it gives me error :
go: github.com/go-xorm/xorm@v0.7.0: github.com/go-xorm/xorm@v0.7.0 requires
github.com/go-xorm/core@v0.0.0-20180322150003-0177c08cee88: invalid pseudo-version: does not match version-control timestamp (expected 20180322142944)

I have updated the go version to latest (go1.20.5) . I tried to install the xorm from https://gitea.com/xorm/xorm  . But still cannot fix the error.